# Get notified when allowing notification setting is changed iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have a scenerio where I have to turn on/off a switch when user enables/disables notifications for an app from system setting. We can determine if notification is enabled or not using  UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.contains(UIUserNotificationType.alert) but what I need is notify VC when the setting is changed.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the user to change the settings he should enter the settings; therefore, app will go to background. I advise you to check the status u=in the AppDelegate in the willEnterForeground function and update the view controller. You may update the view controller by having an instance or by using Notification Center.

Comment: I thought of this solution but there are edge cases where this doesn't work. The user can edit settings from within the app, there is an option for that. Also, when the use first selects their settings for the first time. Those two edge cases are instances where the user doesn't leave the app to change the settings. 

In reality there is no way to do this, therefore it has to be done in a hacky way